# Example test cases for hypothesis based strategies?

Tags: python-hypothesis

What is considered current best practice to test own strategies which are based on [hypothesis](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis-python)? There are e.g. tests about how good examples shrink [HypothesisWorks/hypothesis-python/tests/quality/test_shrink_quality.py](https://github.com/HypothesisWorks/hypothesis-python/blob/master/tests/quality/test_shrink_quality.py). However I could not find examples so far which test the data generation functionality of strategies (in general, performance, etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hypothesis runs a series of [health checks](https://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/healthchecks.html) on each strategy you use, including for time taken to generate data and the proportion of generation attempts that succeed - try e.g. `none().map(lambda x: time.sleep(2)).example()` or `integers().map(lambda x: x % 17 == 0).example()` to see them in action!

In most cases you do not need to test your own strategies beyond using these healthchecks.  Instead, I would check that your *tests* are sufficient by using [a code coverage library](https://coverage.readthedocs.io).

Comment: Right, the HealthChecks are quite helpful. Is there a way to agregate the coverage of several subsequent hypothesis runs? (In case the achievable full coverage is not achieved during a single run.)

Comment: Thanks to a really cool internal feature, you shouldn't need to!  When you run a Hypothesis test, it runs under branch coverage, and biases the example generation to cover as many branches as possible.  A diverse set of base inputs is also saved in the database, so this shouldn't backslide much at all.  If you somehow *still* have uncovered paths, I'd suggest adding an explicit @example or more tests rather than aggregating multiple runs.

Comment: Wow, that's a really powerful feature!!! In my current use case I am using Hypothesis not for Python code testing but remote system testing. This means it won't help me in this case...